# mesh and meshgrid dimension convenience

Tags: matlab, mesh

I have a dimension problem by using mesh-plot.The following example works good but I want to plot `mesh(zz,TT,u(:,:,2,1))` instead of `mesh(u(:,:,2,1))`. At this case, the dimensions do not agree and matlab gives error. How can I order this dimension problem?

```
clear;
z=linspace(0,10,5);
T=linspace(0,20,50);
for j=1:length(T)-1
    for i=1:length(z)
         u(i,j,2,1)=z(i)*T(j)+10;
    end
end
figure(1)
[zz,TT]=meshgrid(z,T);
mesh(u(:,:,2,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be simplified as:

```
z = linspace(0,10,5);
T = linspace(0,20,50);
[zz,TT] = ndgrid(z, T(1:end-1));
uu = zz.*TT + 10;
%u(:,:,2,1) = uu;
mesh(zz, TT, uu)
```

I take out one less element from T, because thats how you filled the matrix `u`. Also note the difference between MESHGRID and NDGRID

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all. Is this what you're looking for?

```
z=linspace(0,10,5);
T=linspace(0,20,50);
for j=1:length(T)
    for i=1:length(z)
         u(i,j)=z(i)*T(j)+10;
    end
end

[TT, zz]=meshgrid(T, z);
```